# Implementing NotificationListenerService in android

Tags: android, android-notifications

I wanted to display notifications that are posted by other applications in the status bar. So I made a button. Clicking the button would call `executeButtonClick()` method. **My code** :

```
public void executeButtonClick(View view) {
    NLService nlService = new NLService();
    if(nlService.getActiveNotifications()!=null) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"InsideIf",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        for (StatusBarNotification sbn : nlService.getActiveNotifications()) {
            String temp = "Package Name: " + sbn.getPackageName() +
                    "\n" + "Title: " + sbn.getNotification().extras.getString("android.title") + "\n" +
                    "Text: " + sbn.getNotification().extras.getCharSequence("android.text");
            String newText = textView.getText().toString() + temp;
            textView.setText(newText);

        }
    }
}
```

But the notification is not shown and I am getting null pointer exception:

`"Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference"`

in the following line: `activity.executeButtonClick(com.example.asus.notificationtest.MainActivity.textView);`

of the `onNotificationPosted()` method mentioned below:

```
public class NLService extends NotificationListenerService {

Context context;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    context = getApplicationContext();
}

@Override
public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
    if(MainActivity.textView != null)
        activity.executeButtonClick(com.example.asus.notificationtest.MainActivity.textView);
    //Toast.makeText(this,"Post from: "+sbn.getPackageName(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onNotificationRemoved(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
    //Toast.makeText(this,"Post from: "+sbn.getPackageName(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: `new NLService()`, `new MainActivity()` – Never directly instantiate an `Activity` or a `Service` yourself. Its `Context` field will not have been properly assigned by the system, which is why you're getting that particular Exception. You'll need to use some other mechanism to pass the necessary data to your `Activity` from the `Service`.

Comment: Can you suggest some ways?

Comment: Depending on your design, you could possibly use extras on `Intent`s with `startActivity()`, or `LocalBroadcastManager`, or some other event bus, or a `ViewModel`/observer setup, etc.

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of steps for getting a Notification listener service working? Are the notifications being detected at all?

Steps: 
1) Request permission in the manifest (for instance):

```
  <service android:name=".TheNotificationListener"
    android:label="NotifiationListener"
    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" />
    </intent-filter>
```

2) Request run time permission from the user:

```
   private void assessPermissions() {
    if(isPermissionRequired()){
        requestNotificationPermission();
    }else{
        startBackground();
    }
}

public boolean isPermissionRequired() {
    ComponentName cn = new ComponentName(this, TheNotificationListener.class);
    String flat = Settings.Secure.getString(this.getContentResolver(), "enabled_notification_listeners");
    final boolean enabled = flat != null && flat.contains(cn.flattenToString());
    return !enabled;
}

private void requestNotificationPermission() {
    Intent intent=new Intent("android.settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS");
    startActivityForResult(intent, 101);
}
```

HINT: Ensure that you remove binding operations from a notification listener service! It took me a day to figure out that I shouldn't have that code in there.

Comment: What binding operation are you talking about?

Comment: What is the the startBackground() method here.